# Cannot write when specifying encoding on open

Tags: perl

Perhaps I am misunderstanding encodings etc, but whenever I specify an encoding on opening an expression under a writeable mode, printing to the handle appears to have no effect.

**Code:**

```
my $string = "one\n";

#open my $handle, '>>', \$string or die "cannot open: $!";
open my $handle, '>>:encoding(UTF-8)', \$string or die "cannot open: $!";

print $handle "two\n";

print $string;
```

**Output:**

```
one
```

**Expected Output:**

```
one
two
```

Could somebody please explain why this is so.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: What is the use of \$string here?

Comment: The third argument to open can be a scalar reference, which is useful if you want to treat a string like a file. Also, its probably better to use IO::String instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are suffering from buffering. Add

```
use IO::Handle qw( );
$handle->autoflush(1);
```

or close the handle before reading from the buffer.

Comment: Thank you, both your suggestions resolve my issue. Do you know why this is only an issue when specifying an encoding?

Comment: The encoding layer probably has its own buffer. I wouldn't count on it always being unbuffered without :encoding.